# How to retrieve default task list from SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint, office365, sharepoint-list

I'm attempting to use the SharePoint REST APIs to view the default task list for a given user, but I can't seem to find the name of the list I want to read from.

I created a new task by going to the "Tasks" app in O365 and following the  "New Task" wizard.

In my code, I obtain a SharePoint token and make a GET call to:
`https://<mysite>.sharepoint.com/personal/<userUPN>/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('WmaAggregatorList_User')`

This just leads to the error:
"List 'WmaAggregatorList_User' does not exist at site with URL..."

Is there a different name for the list I'm trying to reach? Where can I find this documented?

Comment: And it's not because of the extra `'` in your code where you specify the list title?

Comment: No. Copy-paste error in the question. Edited to fix.

Comment: Have you tried `/_api/web/Lists` to find the list?

Comment: Did you solve this yet?